Error BCP080: The expression is involved in a cycle Bicep file in azure while deployment
I have exported a azure resource group that contains many services e.g apimanagement,webapp,databae,virtual network etc
Now i want to deploy this template to the other resource group but getting error below
@secure()
param apis_uat_policy_detail_path string

@secure()
param apis_uat_policy_detail_v1_path string

@secure()
param users_1_lastName string
param sites_fapp_eus_fsps_u_01_name string = 'fapp-eus-fsps-u-01'
param vaults_kv_eus_fsps_u_01_name string = 'kv-eus-fsps-u-01'
resource service_apim_eus_fsps_u_01_name_resource 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2023-09-01-preview' = {
  name: service_apim_eus_fsps_u_01_name
  location: 'East US'
  sku: {
    name: 'Basic'
    capacity: 1
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: 'ashu@gmail.com'
    publisherName: 'FS-UAT'
    notificationSenderEmail: 'apimgmt-noreply@mail.windowsazure.com'
    hostnameConfigurations: [
      {
        type: 'Proxy'
        hostName: '${service_apim_eus_fsps_u_01_name}.azure-api.net'
        negotiateClientCertificate: false
        defaultSslBinding: false
        certificateSource: 'BuiltIn'
      }
      {
        type: 'Proxy'
        hostName: 'fspsapi-fsps-uat.xceedance.com'
        negotiateClientCertificate: false
        certificate: {
          expiry: '2025-04-19T16:34:55+00:00'
          thumbprint: 'B199FC420816C01B7FB532C61'
          subject: 'CN=*.aaaa.com'
        }
        defaultSslBinding: true
        certificateSource: 'Custom'
      }
    ]
    customProperties: {
      'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Protocols.Tls10': 'False'           'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Ciphers.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256': 'false'
    }
    virtualNetworkType: 'None'
    disableGateway: false
    natGatewayState: 'Unsupported'
    apiVersionConstraint: {}
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    privateEndpointConnections: [
      {
        id: service_apim_eus_u_01_name_pe_apim_eus_fsps_u_0.id #here is the error
        name: 'pe-apim-eus-fsps-u-0'
        type: 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/privateEndpointConnections'
        properties: {
          privateEndpoint: {}
          privateLinkServiceConnectionState: {
            status: 'Approved'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    legacyPortalStatus: 'Disabled'
    developerPortalStatus: 'Enabled'
  }
}


this is the very small part of the code ,getting this error through the template.

What is the error message you are receiving. @Ashu

Need error message details

i think the error message is the post title but need more information for sure.

id: service_apim_eus_u_01_name_pe_apim_eus_fsps_u_0.id #here is the error => can you add the service_apim_eus_u_01_name_pe_apim_eus_fsps_u_0 resource in your post. there are some missing piece to be able to reproduce the issue.

Is the error coming with only the given apim code part or how? @Ashu

getting this error throught the bicep file

i tried adding the service_apim_eus_u_01_name_pe_apim_eus_fsps_u_0  but no solution

Can you share the complete code once? @Ashu

where @Jahnavi?
Here only?

I am trying to export the template of apim and app service from Azure and deploy it to another resource group. I will update you if that works. @Ashu

Are you downloading the template in JSON format and then converting to bicep? @Ashu

yes like that@Jahnavi

Let me try and update here. @Ashu

do you need code? @Jahnavi

If you want to move the resources to another resource group, you can also click on Deploy option after exporting the template. Is that works for you? @Ashu

i do not want to move the resource
i want to the replicate the resources of one resouce group to the other by changing the name of services

So, you want to have the same configuration but with different names. It means new resources! Right? @Ashu

correct @Jahnavi

Yes you can achieve it with the Deploy option. @Ashu

After exporting the template, you can click on Deploy and then custom template screen appears. Select the resource group and modify the names for deployment. Have you tried it? @Ashu

yes,then only getting that circular error @Jahnavi


Error BCP080: The expression is involved in a cycle Bicep file in azure while deployment:

The above message is one of the bicep error codes given here in the MS Doc which typically occurs when decompiling the template from ARM Json to Bicep as the template structures differs from one to another.
This error occurs when a bicep compiler finds that, a parameter or resource is pointing out itself. It means the resource is having a circular dependency on the resource and themselves depend on the current resource while deploying it.
Note: I have worked on the similar issue here. Reference SO.

Thanks @Thomas for pointing in the direction which I thought of. The issue is with the privateendpointconnections block in your code.
The id here is creating a continuous dependency between the APIM instance and private endpoint. In order to resolve the conflict, remove the block and a separate resource provider for having private end point connections with Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/privateEndpointConnections as shown below.
resource privateEndpointConnection 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/privateEndpointConnections@2023-09-01-preview' = {
  name: 'lat-eus-fsps-u-0'
  parent: service_apim_eus_fsps_u_01_name_resource
  properties: {
    privateLinkServiceConnectionState: {
      status: 'Approved'
    }
  }
}

